# Android Studio PageViewer findViewById(R.Id.FragmentIteam) returns null

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I got a PageViewer with 3 Fragments (Home, Register, Login). I want to have the text from an EditText of the Login Fragment. If i call findViewById it returns everytime null. So what do I wrong?
MyPageViewer.java:

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public MyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initMyScroller();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    private void initMyScroller() {
        try {
            Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
            Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            scroller.setAccessible(true);
            scroller.set(this, new MyScroller(getContext()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public class MyScroller extends Scroller {
        public MyScroller(Context context) {
            //super(context, new LinearInterpolator()); // my LinearInterpolator
            super(context, new DecelerateInterpolator());
        }

        @Override
        public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
            super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, duration);
        }
    }




}
```

LoginFragment.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;


public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {


    public LoginFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static LoginFragment newInstance(){
        LoginFragment frag = new LoginFragment();
        return frag;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);



    }

}
```

fragment_login.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">



    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">



            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Username / Email"

                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_user"
                android:drawablePadding="15dp"/>


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_pw"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Passwort"


                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock"
                android:drawablePadding="15dp"/>

        <com.ornach.nobobutton.NoboButton

            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:onClick="GoToMenu"
            app:nb_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:nb_borderColor="#666"
            app:nb_borderWidth="1dp"
            app:nb_focusColor="#DDD"
            app:nb_text="ANMELDEN"
            app:nb_textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final int TOTAL_PAGE=3;

    private int sHeight;
    private int sWidth;

    View navBackground, navBottom;
    View navHome, navLogin, navRegister;
    EditText edt_pw, edt_login;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    public static byte[] getSHA(String input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        return md.digest(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    public static String toHexString(byte[] hash)
    {

        BigInteger number = new BigInteger(1, hash);
        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder(number.toString(16));
        while (hexString.length() < 32)
        {
            hexString.insert(0, '0');
        }

        return hexString.toString();
    }

    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_startup);
        SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("SystemSettings", 0); // 0 - for private mode
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();


        if ((pref.getInt("avi", 0)) == 0) {
           editor.putInt("avi", 1);
            editor.commit();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, instruction.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        screenMeasurement();


        navBackground = findViewById(R.id.img_nav_bg);
        navBottom = findViewById(R.id.navbottom);
        navHome = findViewById(R.id.nav_home);
        navLogin = findViewById(R.id.nav_login);
        navRegister = findViewById(R.id.nav_register);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(2);








        navBackground.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int w = (int) (sWidth*2.5);
                int h =  w/2;
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams bgParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) navBackground.getLayoutParams();
                bgParams.width = w;
                bgParams.height = h;
                //bgParams.leftMargin =  -1*((w/2)-(sWidth/2));
                bgParams.bottomMargin = (int) (-1*(h/2.5));
                navBackground.requestLayout();


                int left = (sWidth/2) - (w/2);
                navBackground.setX(left);

                resizeNavIcon(navHome,w);
                resizeNavIcon(navLogin,w);
                resizeNavIcon(navRegister,w);

            }
        });

    }

    private void resizeNavIcon(View view, int bgWidth){
        int iconWidth = (bgWidth*43)/500;
        int m = iconWidth/15;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams btnParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        btnParams.width = iconWidth;
        btnParams.height = iconWidth;
        btnParams.leftMargin = (int) (m*1.5);
        btnParams.rightMargin = (int) (m*1.5);
        btnParams.topMargin = m;
        btnParams.bottomMargin = m;
        view.setLayoutParams(btnParams);
        view.requestLayout();

        int p = (int) (iconWidth/3.5);
        //Log.e("TAG","width: "+iconWidth+"  Padding: "+ p);
        view.setPadding(p,p,p,p);
    }

    private void screenMeasurement(){
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        sHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        sWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    }



    public void onNavClick(View view){
        moveBackground(view);

        int d = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(d);
    }


    private void moveBackground(View view){
        int c = view.getLeft()+(view.getWidth()/2);

        int left = c-(navBackground.getWidth()/2);
        //navBackground.setX(left);
        navBackground.animate().translationX(left);
    }

    public void GoToMenu(View view) {

        edt_login = findViewById(R.id.edt_login);
        edt_pw = findViewById(R.id.edt_pw);




        Log.d("Test","PW: "+edt_pw.getText().toString());



    }


    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return RegisterFragment.newInstance();
                case 2:
                    return LoginFragment.newInstance();
                default:
                    return HomeFragment.newInstance();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TOTAL_PAGE;
        }

    }

}
```

activity_startup.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_nav_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/nav_background"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <e.marco.gymdiary.MyViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/navbottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            >

            <com.ornach.magicicon.IconButton
                android:id="@+id/nav_login"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:onClick="onNavClick"
                android:padding="0dp"
                app:mi_fontText="&#xf234;"
                app:mi_iconColor="#FFF"
                app:mi_typeface="font_awesome"
                android:tag="0"
                app:mi_shape="oval"/>

            <com.ornach.magicicon.IconButton
                android:id="@+id/nav_home"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:onClick="onNavClick"
                android:padding="0dp"
                app:mi_fontText="&#xf015;"
                app:mi_iconColor="#FFF"
                app:mi_typeface="font_awesome"
                android:tag="1"
                app:mi_shape="oval"/>

            <com.ornach.magicicon.IconButton
                android:id="@+id/nav_register"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:onClick="onNavClick"
                android:padding="0dp"
                app:mi_fontText="&#xf007;"
                app:mi_iconColor="#FFF"
                app:mi_typeface="font_awesome"
                android:tag="2"
                app:mi_shape="oval"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

The line `edt_pw.getText().toString()` returns nothing. Please explain it exactly. Thank you.

BR
Marco

Comment: I will see the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"You should design each fragment as a modular and reusable activity component." taken from https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

At the moment your login fragment is not modular, it depends on the MainActivity.java to supply the `onClick` method `GoToMenu`

While LoginFragment will exist when the `GoToMenu` button is clicked (because the button is inside the Fragment), the scope of the

```java
edt_login = findViewById(R.id.edt_login);
edt_pw = findViewById(R.id.edt_pw);
```

In MainActivity.java is wrong

A better method is to handle the button click inside the Fragment itself maintaining the modularity.

To do this is remove `android:onClick="GoToMenu"` from the `fragment_login.xml` file.

In `LoginFragment.java` set an `OnClickListener` to the button

`onCreateView` in `LoginFragment.java` would look like :-

```java
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

Button gotoMenuButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
gotoMenuButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              EditText edt_login = rootView.findViewById(R.id.edt_login);
              EditText edt_pw = rootView.findViewById(R.id.edt_pw);
            }
         };
   return rootView;
}
```

Then depending on what you want to do with these values you might need to create an interface to communicate these out of the Fragment.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As per your code `edt_pw` is defined in ***fragment_login.xml*** and you are accessing `edt_pw` in ***MainActivity.java*** which will definitely return **null**, you need to initialise that in ***LoginFragment***

I can either do one of the following:

1. Keep the instance of **LoginFragment** and access `edt_pw` (good approach)
2. Create an interface listener and pass a listener to **LoginFragment** and pass the value of `edt_pw` to **MainActivity**

Comment: I am a beginner so can you give me a example that I can understand it better? Thank you

Comment: you can do something like this:     `EditText edt_pw = loginFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.edt_pw);`

Comment: Ok I think understand the logic.
But the next Problem is 'LoginFrament.getView()' returns null

Comment: you need to save the instance of LoginFragment when you are initialising in pager adapter.